How to use tweens to spin a wheel clockwise in Godot Engine?
How can I spin a roulette wheel in a clockwise direction using a tween?
I've successfully managed to rotate counter-clockwise to the exact segment, but changing the direction to go clockwise is still a problem.

extends Control


const DEGREES := 360.0
@onready var wheel := $Front as TextureRect

enum Directions {CCLOCKWISE=-1, CLOCKWISE=1}
@export var direction := Directions.CLOCKWISE
@export var segment_count := 8
@export var spin_time := 2.0
@export var spin_count := 1
var spinning := false


func spin(to_segment: int) -> void:
    if spinning:
        return
    spinning = true
    print(to_segment)
    randomize()
    var d := DEGREES / segment_count
    var r := d / 2
    var t := (to_segment-1) * d - r
    t += fposmod(wheel.rotation_degrees, DEGREES)
    #t += randf_range(0, d)  # add slight offset
    var target := wheel.rotation_degrees - (spin_count * DEGREES) - t

    var tween := create_tween().set_trans(Tween.TRANS_CUBIC).set_ease(Tween.EASE_OUT)
    await tween.tween_property(wheel, "rotation_degrees", target, spin_time).finished
    spinning = false


func _input(event: InputEvent) -> void:
    if event is InputEventMouseButton:
        if event.pressed:
            spin(randi() % segment_count + 1)  # pick random segment



solved after some rest, now can work on both directions.
extends Control


const CIRCLE := 360.0
@onready var wheel := $Front as TextureRect

enum Directions {CCLOCKWISE=-1, CLOCKWISE=1}
@export var direction := Directions.CLOCKWISE
@export var segment_count := 8
@export var spin_time := 2.0
@export var spin_count := 1
var spinning := false


func spin(to_segment:=0) -> void:
    if spinning:
        return
    spinning = true

    if !to_segment: to_segment = randi() % segment_count + 1  # pick random segment if not prodived

    print(to_segment)
    var sd := CIRCLE / segment_count
    var rot := (to_segment-1) * sd - sd / 2
    rot += fposmod(wheel.rotation_degrees, CIRCLE)
    rot += randf_range(0, sd)  # pick random area in segment

    if direction == Directions.CCLOCKWISE:
        rot = fposmod(CIRCLE - rot, CIRCLE)

    var tween := create_tween().set_trans(Tween.TRANS_CUBIC).set_ease(Tween.EASE_OUT)
    await tween.tween_property(
        wheel,
        "rotation_degrees",
        wheel.rotation_degrees + ((spin_count * CIRCLE) + rot) * -direction, spin_time
        ).finished
    spinning = false


func _input(event: InputEvent) -> void:
    if event is InputEventMouseButton:
        if event.pressed:
            randomize()
            spin()

```


This answer would be even better if it included a brief summary of what you changed and why that solved the problem, to help future readers understand your solution.

Maybe I'm not familiar enough with  Godot here, but from the indentation, it looks like you set spinnging = true, and then after setting up the tweening via await, set spinning = false. Would that not be easier to set spinning = !to_segment: to_segment = randi() % segment_count + 1  and then check for spinning during the if statement? Or is the spinning = false part of .finished?
